# Session variables not being set in expressjs

Tags: node.js, session, express

I've tried many ways of setting the session variables but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. The problem more precisely is that the session (custome) variables are not being passed to other routes (so they aren't  being stored in the default MemoryStore presumably).
All of the code is available at https://github.com/codexa/pictroid/blob/session/app.js

This is the portion of code for assigning the session variable (https://github.com/codexa/pictroid/blob/session/app.js#L304-311)

```
console.log(req.session);
req.session.regenerate(function(){
    // Store the user's primary key
    // in the session store to be retrieved,
    // or in this case the entire user object
    req.session.user = "some user";
    req.session.auth = true;
});
```

I'm aware of the fact that this is async and the proceeding code will be executed while this does but making it synchronous doesn't solve the problem.

As an example, I'm trying to retrieve the custom "req.session.user" in the root dir route (https://github.com/codexa/pictroid/blob/session/app.js#L87-L88)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.session.auth);
...
```

So can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you needing to regenerate the session?

Comment: You also set `secure: true` for your cookie, which means the cookie will only work for https. It doesn't look like you are using https for your server.

Comment: I'm regenerating the cookie because it's advised to do so (to prevent fixation  - https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js). So in dev environment, I shouldn't set secure to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set `secure: true` if you are using http because cookies with `secure: true` will only be sent for http**s** requests. If you want to keep `secure: true`, you will need to start an http**s** server instead. If you are doing this only for development purposes, then you can just temporarily remove `secure: true` until you put your code into production (where you use https).

Also on an unrelated note, you can avoid regenerate() and the session fixation problem by only starting a session after a successful authentication and for authenticated routes. This will also help decrease the number of sessions in your session store from visitors who never sign in or crawlers (unless of course you need to store session data for unauthenticated users).