# expressJS creates new session every page load

Tags: node.js, session, express, nginx, vagrant

Running locally everything is fine but when I deploy my app using vagrant to a virtual box or to amazon and put it behind nginx, redirects and page loads refresh `req.session`.

Here's the nginx configuration: https://github.com/newslynx/automation/blob/master/provisioning/templates/app-nginx.conf.j2

And how I'm setting up my session store in the Express app: https://github.com/newslynx/newslynx-app/blob/master/lib/app.js

And where I'm setting the apikey and org ids on the session, which are getting cleared when the user gets redirected to `'/'`
https://github.com/newslynx/newslynx-app/blob/master/lib/routes/organizations.js#L55-L65

I've tried combinations of `saveUninitialized` and `resave` to `true` and `false`. I've switched to in-memory as well as Redis-backed session store with no change. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was due to the app being loaded in an https context and thus not setting cookies over http. This answer has more detail: [Session variables not being set in expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839085/session-variables-not-being-set-in-expressjs)